# Save certain sheets as PDF

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf

I have an excel workbook, where the end user does some selection, based on which the sheets which needs to be saved as a single PDF, are enlisted in Sheet 1, cell B10 like this (E1, E2, E3, E4...)

Now I have tried this macro below, but it does not work properly, the reasons are given below the code:

```
Sub pdff()

   Sheets("E1").Activate
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
   Sheets("E2").Activate
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
   Sheets("E3").Activate
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("E1", "E2","E3")).Select
   Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
      "C:\Users\Damon\Desktop\pdfmaker.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
      True
End Sub
```

The problems with the code:

- After the code runs, it groups the sheets together, which has to be
  ungrouped manually.
- The code saves the areas outside of the set print area (which does
  not happen if I save each sheet manually as PDF)
- The code is not dynamic, it does not pick up the sheet names from
  cell B10

Answer (score 1):

With:

[image]

This version will meet all your goals:

```
Sub pdff()
    Dim s As String, ary, a, sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    s = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B10").Text
    ary = Split(s, ",")

    For Each a In ary
        Sheets(a).Select
        Sheets(a).Activate
        Sheets(a).Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea).Select
    Next a

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ary).Select

    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Damon\Desktop\pdfmaker.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        True

    sh.Select
End Sub
```

Just make sure you have a *Sheet1* as well as the *E1* sheets.

Comment: First of all, a big thanks for answering the question. The code works, except for one small error, its inserting lot of blank pages. Now I know what is happening. Sheet "E1" has 11 pages, while "E2" and "E3" are only 1 page each. After I run the code and go back to sheet E2 and E3, i see the same print area of E1 is selected, which I think is causing all those blank pages. I think it is applying the print area of the first sheet to the rest of the sheets. Checked with opposite case also, where it is truncating the pages.

Comment: @Firee I am sorry, but I cannot replicate your problem without access to your workbook.

Comment: @Firee  In my edit, I have placed an `Activate` as well as a `Select` in the loop .......................... **does this help the issue ??**

Comment: Here's the link to my workbook. Your last edit did not help with the issue. Hope you understand if I have omitted some parts of my workbook due to confidentiality. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4zXiAcJ1pQTazJSdHNRaFVUX1U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have resolved the issue by hiding all the extra rows in all of my sheets. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it possible to expand the scope of your macro? I need to make certain words bold & italicized in my sheets. So can your macro first make a copy of the sheets in the temp folder, then change the contents to text, then apply the formatting to those desired words. Note: that the words are different for different sheets.

Comment: @Firee  **YES** ...............We need more details to proceed further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37654/discussion-between-firee-and-garys-student).